# Calling functions correctly in premade javascript

Tags: javascript

I got this HTML code:

```
<head>
<link href="default.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme1.css" title="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme2.css" title="theme2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme3.css" title="theme3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<ul id="dropdown">
  <li> Choose theme
    <ul> 
      <li id="stylesheet1" > <a href="#"> Default </a></li>
      <li id="stylesheet2" > <a href="#"> Theme 1 </a></li>
      <li id="stylesheet3" > <a href="#"> Theme 2 </a></li>
      <li id="stylesheet4" > <a href="#"> Theme 3 </a></li>
   </ul>
 </li> 
</ul>

</body>
```

And I got this is the code in the separate file javascript.js:

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);



// Last part

function initate()
{
var style1 = document.getElementById("stylesheet1");
var style2 = document.getElementById("stylesheet2");
var style3 = document.getElementById("stylesheet3");
var style4 = document.getElementById("stylesheet4");

style1.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("default"); 
    return false;
    };
style2.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme1"); 
    return false;
    };
style3.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme2");
    return false
    };
style4.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme3"); 
    return false
    };            
}

window.onload = initate;
```

I'm new to javascripts and I haven't written this script myself (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) and I managed to create the last part (as shown by comment in code) by myself to have the eventhandlers separate in the javascript file as I want and this part enables the style sheets to be changed the way I want it. But I can't figure out how to get the cookies to work as well to get the themes I'm using to be saved.

EDIT:

Since I'm new I still have a hard time figuring this code out but I've tried changing the last function `initiate` and used onClick eventhandlers for the saving of cookies but I can't get it to work. 
I've used this:

```
style1.onclick = function () {
    createcookie(T1, style, 7);
}
```

And

```
document.getElementById("stylesheet1").onclick(createCookie(T1, style, 7));
```

And when I did the changing of style sheets didn't work anymore.

Comment: Not sure if that's a typing mistake or not, but you forgot the `>` after `</head`, and also didn't close the `<ul>`.

Comment: start by understanding the different parts of a cookie  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

Comment: @DJDavid98 It was just silly typos, updated now

Comment: Well, at least you were lucky enough to use [Peter-Paul Koch's cookie functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). Try reading Peter-Paul's article too. Another option as well is to send the theme name/ID to the server asynchronously and create the cookie on the server (which will return the cookie in the response), *and* save it to the session and/or user settings. Or you could just keep it in the session, or a table in the DB until someone logins then put it the session, which could then be used to toggle the theme includes as appropriate. All kinds of crazy ways to milk this cow.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I have read that article but I'm still not into enough of javascripting to see where and how I should bake in whatever is needed into my code.. Whichever way that works is fine for me.

Comment: One big no no, don't wait until `unload` to swap the theme name into the cookie storing the theme name. Do it when it changes. There's no reason to wait, and there's no guarantee it `unload` will fire. When it's toggled, update the cookie value.

Comment: Well, here's the issue. You're asking for someone to just do it for you so it'll get done, kinda like you're too busy to do it. SO, unfortunately, is not a coding service. What is the question? Is there someone who will do it for you? Or...? Something else more productive for us to participate in?

Comment: @JaredFarrish And by this you mean that I should move this part? `function(e) {
      var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
      createCookie("style", title, 365);
    }` And to where?

Comment: I guess you are right... I've taken on a bit to hard project for me it seems

Comment: If all you need is a script to handle it you can drop in and forget about, there's several that are good and been around. If you were using jQuery, [you'd have more than a couple to choose from](http://www.net-kit.com/10-practical-jquery-style-switchers/), including [jQuery UI Themeswitcher, which uses cookies](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Luckily, you can review the [source at GitHub](https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher/blob/master/jquery.themeswitcher.js) and review the methodology in general. There's others, including simple Javascript only ones.

Comment: I'd like simple javascript one if you happen to sit on a good source of it :)

Comment: The Themeswitcher method that handles the cookie part you can see here: https://github.com/harborhoffer/Super-Theme-Switcher/blob/master/jquery.themeswitcher.js#L334 Simplify what you're trying to do. Each time someone runs a `switchTheme()` function, it saves a value with a key to cookie at the same time, and when the page loads, a small script gets the cookie theme if available and runs the `Themeswitcher` onload.

Comment: Move that part you had `onunload` to the `SetActiveStylesheet()` function. Don't make it harder on yourself. When someone switches, save it to the cookie.

Comment: Still can't figure out how to do it :(

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've read through those instructions but I still can't figure out how to solve the problem. I've tried around a lot with it but I can't wrap my head around how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
style1.onclick = function () {
    createcookie(T1, style, 7);
}
```

because what you do is you set the `onclick` handler to a function. You don't call the function there, you just give it away so that someone else (the browser) can call it.

This doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("stylesheet1").onclick(createCookie(T1, style, 7));
```

because you call the function right there. What you do is:

1. Invoke `createCookie` with 3 parameters
2. Invoke `onclick` with the return value from `createCookie`

What you want is probably something like:

```
document.getElementById("stylesheet1").onclick = function() {
    createCookie(T1, style, 7);
};
```

what this does, is create an *anonymous function* and sets this function to the `onclick` property of the element. This anonymous function, when called, will call the `createCookie` function.

The reason you need to do this, is because you have parameters to `createCookie`, and those parameters must be bound somewhere until it's time to call the function.

Comment: Yes, this does work, thank you. Though it still doesn't keep the themes I've chosen for when I reload the page..

Comment: @Benji of course not, when you reload the page everything is back to normal. This is definitely the expected behaviour. The browser doesn't magically "remember" anything that happened in javascript last time you visited the page.

Comment: Yes, I know that but now that this script does save the chosen .css as a cookie (if I understood everything right), how do I then read and reload the same .css for the next time the page is visited?

Comment: @Benji, oh I completely missed the *purpose* of the question. The implementation is really bad since it uses document.onunload which won't work with Opera or Chrome.

Comment: I got suggested to move the code `function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}` into my `setActiveStyleSheet` function and I tried it but it didn't work when I did. As mentioned before, I'm very new to javascripts..

Comment: Do you have any other solutions on how to solve this or should I move it into the mentioned function? And if so, how should it be placed?